# Spring web-socket message size

Tags: activemq-classic, messaging, stomp, spring-websocket, sockjs

I am implementing an application using spring websockets, stompjs and sockjs. The messages that I am currently sending are working fine when the message size is less than the configured buffer size limit, however its hard for me to judge what the size would be as it would depend on the user selection and the message is then built on it.

My question here is

1) Who handles the message size limit, is it the message broker, right now I am using the default message broker that comes with spring, does it help if I move to ActiveMQ and do I need to do something on ActiveMQ's configuration to change this message size?

2) I was looking into partial messaging in spring websockets, but I couldnt find any demonstration of it. Can you please let me know?